# Как создать свою кнопку для ACF Wysiwyg tinymce?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, acf, wysiwyg

Необходимо создать свою кнопку и добавить ее на toolbar.
Такой код, хорошо работает для обычного редактора WP:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'wdd_mce_format', function ( editor, url ) {
    editor.addButton( 'wdd_mce_format', {
        active: true,
        tooltip: 'Formating the List',
        text : 'Formating the List',
        icon : false,
        type : 'button',
        onclick : function () {
            do_stuff_here('')
        }
    } );
} );
```

Для ACF редактора tinymce он выполняется, но кнопка не появляется. 
Какие есть идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эврика!!!*[куча матюков]* оказалось что инициализация ACF Wysiwyg toolbars перебивает подгрузку плагинов tinymce.
Решение :

```
add_filter( 'acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars' , 'my_toolbars'  );
function my_toolbars( $toolbars )
{
    return array();
}
```

После этого все плагины tinymce работают в штатном режиме.